# Can't get Value from multiple selection list box, getting EF proxy instead

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, listbox

I'm new to WPF/C# so perhaps I am missing something obvious. I am trying to get values from a multiple selection listbox to add to a query. When I try to get selected items from a list box, I get what I think is a proxy value from the entity (System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Subject_E99+quite a  long string of characters).

I create the Listbox like this:

```
// load list to Subjects listbox
var justsubjects = from s in _context.Subjects
     orderby s.meaning
     select s;
lstSubject.ItemsSource = justsubjects.ToList();
lstSubject.DisplayMemberPath = "meaning";
```

And then try to add it to the query like so:

```
// do loop to get all subjects from LISTBOX into query
foreach (var item in lstSubject.SelectedItems)
{
  var subjtext = item.ToString();
  MessageBoxResult searchsubjects = MessageBox.Show(subjtext); 
  searchresult = searchresult.Where(a => a.Subjects.Any(s => s.meaning == subjtext));
 }
```

When I create the listbox like this:

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Subject Code" Binding="{Binding subject1}" Width="*" />
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Meaning" Binding="{Binding meaning}" Width="2*"/>
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Stage" Binding="{Binding stage}" Width="*"/>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

I can see all the values for the subjects in the list box.

Comment: You probably forgot `SelectedValuePath`.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I did forget to set SelectedValuePath.  But I am still having trouble pulling it from within the foreach loop.

Comment: The way I solved this problem was to set a SelectedValuePath on my original list box. But that still did not solve my problem of getting the multiple selected values for use in my query.  So, I created a second listbox (selectedSubjects) and sent any selected items from the first textbox into it - selectedSubjects.Items.Add(lstSubject.SelectedValue.ToString());     This gave me a nicely formatted list of selected items in the second list box.  Then I looped through items in the second listbox to add them to my query statement.  Hope this helps someone.